# How to edit files which are made by Laradock workspace

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, laradock

I've newly started to use **Laradock** to build my Laravel projects but I have a problem in editing the files such as Controllers, Models, etc which are made by the **php artisan** command in the Laradock workspace. The reason is the user in the workspace is a root and on the other side, I'm trying to edit the file in my editor by a common user. So every time I have to run the command **chmod -R 777 /newCreatedFile.php** to change the permission. So is there any solution to handle this problem?

By the way my OS is ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [Laradock Getting Started guide](https://laradock.io/getting-started/), it explains how to get Laradock running as a specified user:

> Note: You can add --user=laradock to have files created as your host’s user. Example:
>
> ```
> docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
> ```

I believe this should solve your issue, as you will no longer have the Docker user running these commands. Try it out!

Note: The core issue may just be that whatever user Laradock is running as is not creating files with group permissions that allows the host machine's user write capabilities, hence why the `--user` flag can be used. It may not actually be running as the `root` user itself.

Comment: The docker container should never run Laravel as root, just has you would never do it in a production server... While the answer is correct I recommend the OP to open an issue in the Laradock repo to make the use of `laradock` user the default one.

Comment: You're right, I'll adjust my answer. It may actually not be `root`, but rather a user group that the OP's host machine's user is not in.